# Selenium NoSuchElementException when the element does exist

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.8

I am working on a discord bot that uses selenium to grab a zoom link off of an instagram account. It has been working perfectly until just today when it started giving the error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[2]/a[1]"}`. I have no idea why this is. I have checked that the Xpath is correct and added a sleep function to allow it time to load. So far the only thing that has worked has been changing the browser that it uses from Chrome to Firefox, however this was done on my local machine and can't be done in the actual code because I have it deployed to heroku with a headless chrome browser running and I don't want to go through the trouble of trying to get Firefox to work since it took me over an hour to get chrome working.

Here is the relevant code:

```
@client.command()
async def zoom(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Retrieving current zoom link from instagram...\nPlease wait...")
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=chrome_options)
    url = "https://instagram.com/profile/"
    driver.get(url)    # load instagram page
    time.sleep(5)
    link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[2]/a[1]').get_attribute("innerHTML")  # Get zoom link

    await ctx.send("Here is the current zoom link:\nhttps://" + link)

    driver.quit()
```

Here is the whole error traceback:

```
2020-06-02T03:45:55.540096+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-02T03:45:55.540174+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "main.py", line 48, in zoom
2020-06-02T03:45:55.540177+00:00 app[worker.1]: link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[2]/a[1]').get_attribute("innerHTML")  # Get zoom link
2020-06-02T03:45:55.540204+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
2020-06-02T03:45:55.540206+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
2020-06-02T03:45:55.540264+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
2020-06-02T03:45:55.540265+00:00 app[worker.1]: 'value': value})['value']
2020-06-02T03:45:55.540305+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
2020-06-02T03:45:55.540305+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.error_handler.check_response(response)
2020-06-02T03:45:55.540306+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
2020-06-02T03:45:55.540306+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
2020-06-02T03:45:55.540375+00:00 app[worker.1]: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[2]/a[1]"}
2020-06-02T03:45:55.540377+00:00 app[worker.1]: (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I really need to get this bot back up and running again.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have not used the escaped characters in the double quotation in the id;

try;

```
//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[2]/a[1]
```

instead of;

```
//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[2]/a[1]
```

Comment: Ok I just tried this but it hasn’t changed anything. I still get the error. Also, my code worked perfectly for about a month and then just stopped working yesterday so I don’t see how that changes anything. It worked before because I was using the single quotes for the string so that the double quotes around the react root didn’t end the string.